# codeigniter - which values reference actual files and which reference classes/functions?

Tags: codeigniter, model, reference, controller

I am doing some tutorials of codeigniter and frustrating myself with some elementary stuff.

I have a model named `math.php`

```
 <?php

class math extends CI_Model{
    public function add($val1, $val2){
        return $val1 + $val2;
    }
}
```

This model is called by a controller named `site.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo "Hi Internet<br> ";
        $this->addStuff();
    }

    public function addStuff()
    {
        $this->load->model("math");
        echo $this->math->add(2,2);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. However for my own clarity, I want to rename `math.php` to `model_math.php`

This obviously breaks the page.

My question is, in my controller, `site.php`

`$this->load->model("model_math");` and

`echo $this->model_math->add(2,2);`

which `model_math` references the physical php file and which references the classname I created inside the physical model php file?

I can't get it to work with a model class name of `math` and a physical php file name of 'model_math.php'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Codeigniter you have to name your class the same as your PHP file name. You will get an error if your PHP file is named "model_math.php" and have in your file:

```
Class Math extends CI_Model
```

Limitation of Codeigniter I suppose...but it wouldn't hurt to standardize all your models and controllers by naming them with the same convention (i.e., *name*_model.php; *name*_controller.php). You will just have to name the class the same.

Comment: Thanks Devin, appreciate your time. Glad it wasn't just me. Thanks.